# Issue with Rstudio (version 1.1.463) Lines in plot do not display correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I got a plot that can be used as an example but this happens with every plot of that has straight diagonal lines, including pie charts.

Example 1:

```
 x <- c(1:5); y <- x 
par(pch=22, col="red") 
par(mfrow=c(2,4)) 

opts = c("l","o","b","c")
for(i in 1:length(opts)){
  heading = paste("type=",opts[i])
  plot(x, y, type="n", main=heading)
  lines(x, y, type=opts[i])
}
```

Example2:

```
data <- data.frame(
  name=c("A","B","C","D","E") ,  
  value=c(3,12,5,18,45)
)
ggplot(data, aes(x=name, y=value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_polar()
```

I get the following plots:
[image]

[image]

As you guys can see neither of those plots have straight lines, I don´t really know a way to fix this.
I am using a laptop with these specs:
Laptop Lenovo G450 (2949-DSS)
Processor Intel Pentium T4400 (2.20 GHz)
Memory de 2GB DDR3, Disco Duro de 250GB
Screen is 14" LED

Comment: For some reason the links to the images did not apper. The links are: [1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUNMi.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/11FxL.jpg

Comment: have you tried making a pdf or a png? what does `dev.cur()` return

Comment: Hi Luis. What platform are you using? Linux / Windows / Mac? Are you using Rstudio?

Comment: @rawr dev.cur() returns  null device 1.

Comment: @AllanCameron I am on windows 7 starter, I am using Rstudio and my laptop is 32 bits

Answer (score 0):

Add a grouping condition. Right now the names are viewed all separately:

```
data <- data.frame(
  name=c("A","B","C","D","E") ,  
  value=c(3,12,5,18,45),
group = rep(1,5))
```

#This gives a stacked bar chart that is then circled with coord_polar is given. Remove coord_polar to see the difference.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = group, y=value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col() + coord_polar("y")
```